# How to build and compile FFmpeg codes in MS Visual Studio and work with the code? Is it possible to edit FFmpeg codes?

Tags: ffmpeg

I work in HM, HTM, VTM and X265 encoders. I can edit the codes of these encoders in visual studio and build it to get modified executables. I actually want to implement the algorithms of my own in these encoders to know how my algorithm impacts the coding efficiency of these encoders. I also want to edit the code of FFmpeg. How to build and compile FFmpeg codes in MS Visual Studio and work with the code? Is it possible to edit FFmpeg?

Comment: Ya I also want to know this but too pay to start a bounty